# In Purescript; What is the difference between -> and =>?

Tags: purescript

While working through PureScript tutorials, the code samples start using "=>" without introducing it. As results I don't understand when to use '=>' and not '->'.

For example this uses '=>':

```
instance showArray :: (Show a) => Show (Array a) where
    show array = "[" <> map show array <> "]"
```

where as this uses '->':

```
greet :: forall r. { name :: String | r} -> String
greet namedThing = "Hello, " ++ namedThing.name
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(Show a) =>` is a type constraint, which restricts the type `a` to instances of the class `Show` and `a -> b` is a type of function. So this code

```
foo :: forall a. (Show a) => a -> b
```

is a function `foo` from `a` to `b` and type `a` must have an instance of class `Show`

In OO languages it would be something like this

```
public B foo<A,B>(A x) where A:IShow
```

Comment: `forall r. { name :: String | r}` seems to be a constraint too. (any r that is an object with a name::String property.)

Comment: No, constrains only use `=>` and type classes.  `{ name :: String | r}` is just an anonymous type. You can define a name for this type `type Name r = { name :: String | r}` `greet :: forall r. Name r -> String`

Comment: `greet :: forall r. Name r -> ` seems like `greet :: (Name r) =>` ... what am I missing?

Comment: Ah.. I think the key may be the difference between "type" and "type classes" where type classes are like C# interfaces, and types are like C# classes.

Comment: Yes, even it isn't 100% accurate, this analogy could work.